# How to make a LÖVE2d executable or installer file without the other dependencies?

Tags: lua, executable, love2d

I make games using [LÖVE2d](https://love2d.org/) and after reading the [game distribution for windows](https://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution#Windows) I was successfully able to make a folder in which there would be the game.exe file which the user has to click to play the game and all of it works properly.

The problem is that along with the game.exe file there are a lot of *.dll* files such as **love.dll, lua51.dll** and so on.

What I need is **ONLY** the **.exe** file so that the user should **NOT** see the dll files at all as they are very annoying.

Is there a way to create only the installer without it being dependent on these files or any other way to do so?

I searched for more than a month now and never found a solution to it.

I would be grateful if someone helps me though this.

Thanks in advance.

**PS: Using lua to program**

Comment: If I try deleting the dll files the game does not run as it is dependent on those files

Comment: I guess you would have to build your own love2d. what's wrong with having multiple files? thats true for pretty much any decent software.

Comment: No, I think you don’t understand. Now, whenever I download a game from the web I get the exe file and then maybe the readme but I don’t get to see any dll files. I want it like that.

Comment: I don't know which kind of software you download but most software is distributed either as a zip file or as some executable setup. only very few, very small programs come as the exectuable progam itself. as soon as your software gets more and more complex and involves libraries you will have some dlls, configuration file, databases....

Comment: Nono, you don’t understand, I am not stating that I don’t want a zip or a installer, all I am telling is that all of my dll files are SEEN WHICH ARE NOT OTHERWISE so is there a way to package them all together to one file or hide them al together but still use them?

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve. I'm just saying that it doesn't make any sense. if you want to have a single executable only you have to build one. but that would defy the whole point of using love2d. the whole point of using an embedded scripting language like Lua here is that you don't have to compile the whole framework. not to mention that you lose all the benefits of DLLs if you link everything statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an *executable packer*.

Try with one of these:

- https://github.com/upx/upx (free software)
- https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/#merging-dlls ($$)

Comment: Thank you, buddy. I forgot to mark this answer as "accepted" earlier.